# Determine if importing a Python module causes side effects

Tags: python

**Without recommending books, tools, software libraries, or more**, please can you tell me if it is possible to determine if importing a Python module causes side effects? Instagram made [a blog post about strict modules](https://instagram-engineering.com/python-at-scale-strict-modules-c0bb9245c834) a while ago with a description of something that sounds like it could do it, but unfortunately it doesn't seem like they ever released any code.

> Strict modules place some limitations on what can happen at module top-level. All module-level code, including decorators and functions/initializers called at module level, must be pure (side-effect free, no I/O). This is verified statically at compile time via the abstract interpreter.

Are there any other ways to do this other than duplicating their work? For example is it possible to use `sys.settrace()` or `sys.setprofile()` to detect when code is executed during import?

Comment: Depends on what you're looking for. For instance, is doing `x = time.time()` during import  a side effect? If nothing else, it makes the module impure...

Comment: Good point, I guess it's not technically a side effect, but to make the problem tractable let's say that it has side effects if it executes any code. I.e. anything other than function and class definitions. I am ok with false positives (i.e. it says it has side effects but it really doesn't).

Comment: You'l have to be more specific about what you consider a side effect. Importing a module may create a `module` instance, it may update `sys.modules`, and it will always bind one or more names in the current namespace. When defining a module, code is *always* executed: `def` statements define functions, variable assignments execute their right-hand expressions, etc.

Comment: If all you care about is that the top level elements of the module imported are `def`s and `class`es or simple assignments, you can verify that with the `ast` module.

Comment: Yeah, it's possible, their blog post demonstrates that it is. Now is it easy to do what they did, maybe with the standard library? Heck no. They wrote their own module loader to statically determine module strictness based on known safe functions and whether they're importing from other strict modules. What really impressed me was their transformation of classes into structs. I think you might be able to do that bit yourself with a decorator returning a function, but holy cow this was a big patch job on Python.

Comment: Hmm I feel like you might be able to do it in a simpler (but maybe less precise) way by tracing bytecode execution and seeing if it calls functions outside of the current module. I will experiment.

Comment: `@functools.lru_cache` comes to mind as a benign call to another module.

Answer (score 4):

The theoretical answer is that you can't determine whether an arbitrary piece of code will have side-effects when run, because if you have an algorithm to test that then you could use it to solve the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). (Just imagine a program which simulates a Turing machine and then prints "Hello world" after the simulation terminates; it has a side-effect if and only if that Turing machine halts.)

The practical answer is that such an algorithm doesn't need to always give the correct answer, so long as (1) it correctly labels all impure code as impure, and (2) it doesn't incorrectly label too much pure code as impure. (Think of the algorithm as not testing whether the code is "pure" or "impure", but testing whether it is "pure" or "not known to be pure".)

It would be totally feasible to define a subset of Python which could only be used to write pure code, and then test whether the given module is written in that subset of Python or whether it uses some feature outside of the subset. A simple test would be "does the module only consist of function definitions without decorators, whose parameters either have no default values or whose default values are literal values?" You could also allow class definitions so long as the body of the class only contains function definitions, so no tricky business like `class A: print('Hello world')`. You could allow variables to be declared globally so long as their initialisers are literals, and so on.

There would be many modules with no side-effects when imported which would not pass this kind of test, but if you come up with a large enough subset of Python that doesn't allow for side-effects, then it might be useful to have a static checker like that.